# Cordova facebook connect plugin is not working on android device- Ionic 1

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

Facebook plugin is not working on android device, however it is working on browser platform. I am using this plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

I followed these steps
-Installed the cordova facebook plugin  using this command and changed the variable names to my app id and app name

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

Next I added the following script in my index.html at the end of the body tag

```
<script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
     FB.init({
      appId: 'myAppId',
      xfbml: true,
      version: '1.1.1'
    });
  };
  (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and then added the following div in my body of index.html as documentation says to do so

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Next I added the following script in by index.html after the script tag of cordova.js

```
<script src='lib/facebook-connect-plugin/index.js'></script>
```

Next I generated the hash key using this command

```
 keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

and added the hash key in facebook app settings

What I am doing wrong or missed anything that causes the application not to run on android

Comment: What you are doing now is including 2 times the facebook SDK. One with the native SDK (cordova plugin add), the other the is the web version (https://connect.facebook.net). You should decide which one to use but not the two ! Also, you can verify logs of the application to see why it crashes. Use `adb logcat` for that.

Comment: Which one should I include??

Comment: Test one and you will see. For me, the best will be the native one.